# How to fire an img resize event in jQuery when the window opens, not on window resize

Tags: jquery, image-resizing, window-resize

I have a script that resizes an image/div dynamically on window resize, but if the viewer opens the window less than full, the image is too large for the viewing area. Here's what I've got (you might find this familiar):

```
<script typ="text/javascript">
        $(window).resize(function() {
            var hgt = $(window).height() - 427;
            var wid = $(window).width() - 603;
            $('.slides_container img').css({
                width:'auto',
                height:hgt,
            });
            $('.slides_container img').css("max-height", 427);
            $('.slides_container img').css("max-width", 603);
            $('.slides_container').css("width", '100%');
            $('.slides_container').height(hgt-10);
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Put following code above </script>:

```
$(document).ready($(window).resize());
```

Comment: It still only reacted to the resize once I adjusted the window's size.

Comment: He's explicitly asking for the image resize event and not window resize.